# redirect adb logcat to android avd

Tags: android, adt, logcat

i want to redirect the Android developer tools logcat output to a file into the virtual device from a shell command, before than running the android app test. 
The command i usually use to redirect the output to a file is:

```
adb shell logcat -v time - f log.txt packageName:F *:E > /folder/log.txt
```

but it puts the log file into a computer directory `(/folder/ in this case)`.
I want to change it with a directory in the virtual device but like above, it says the folder does not exist. 
There is way to do it via shell command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
adb shell "logcat -v time -f /mnt/sdcard/log.txt packageName:F *:E"
```

to accomplish it all in one command from the host shell.  You do not need the redirect when you use the -f flag, in fact the redirect would not capture anything if you have directed the output of logcat to a file rather than to stdout.

If that is not working, it is either because you are using a version of Android which mounts the external storage at some other path, **or you do not have an emulated sdcard attached to your virtual device**.

You can investigate either of these problems by examining the output of

```
adb shell mount
```

If you do not have an sdcard at all on your AVD, follow the emulator documentation instructions for creating and attaching one.

**For testing purposes only** there may be other paths than the sdcard at which you can write, particularly on an emulator where the adb shell runs as root, for example on some versions `/data/local` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one `adb shell` then `#logcat>/sdcard/log.txt` now i am sure about the results.you just need a command prompt window to be opened for adb shell,that's not so bad i guess.

Comment: is the same than mine, with the only difference that filter the output at a particular level. the folder /sdcard/log.txt does not exist

Comment: does not work: adb does not signal any error but in the path specified (/sdcard/) there are no log.txt.

Comment: well,it is working for me.check if your emulator has an sdcard or not

Comment: now works, probably 'cause before i had some java logger redirected to another file and i cannot redirect same outputs to different files.